# How to disable page-break before a long iframe while printing?

Tags: html, css, iframe, printing, page-break

There is a page-break before a long iframe while printing the webpage however the iframe itself has the possibility of breaking into different pages. I want to avoid page-break and blank space before iframe.

I tried disabling page-break-before but didn't work:

Check the output below **by pressing the print button**:

```css
 @media print {
    iframe {
      page-break-before: avoid;
    }
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="window.print()">Print this page</button>

<iframe style="width:100%;height:1900px" style="border:1" src="https://www.example.com"></iframe>
```